# android: how to create a list with recipes, which when opened displays strings from an xml resource file in textviews?

Tags: android, xml, listview

im trying to create an android app for recipes.
the problem is i dont know how to use what was clicked for searching through an xml resource file.btw ignore the weird language :)

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                // selected item
                String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                String sastojci = ***WHAT DO I PUT HERE DO DISPLAY THE INGREDIENTS FROM A XML RESOURCE FILE BASED ON WHAT I CLICKED ( name of the recipe is what is clicked) ?***

                // sad tu stavit nesto da cita xml po string productu.

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Recept.class);
                i.putExtra("product", product);
                i.putExtra("sastojci", sastojci);
                startActivity(i);
```

EXAMPLE OF THE XML RESOURCE FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="Naan"> 
       <item>PripremaTežina:Jednostavno
1
Germu zamutiti sa vodom i secerom i ostaviti da nadodje
2
Brasno prosijati, dodati nadoslu germu, jaje , mljieko i so.
Dodavati postepeno toplu vodu dok se ne dobije glatko tijesto ljepljivo za prste.
Ostaviti da nadodje, zatim podijeliti na manje loptice ( meni je izaslo osam).
3
Oblikovati ih i ostaviti da nadodju jos 15-tak minuta.
Razvuci lagano tijesto, oklagijom ili rukama, debljine oko 1 cm.
4
U medjuvremenu zagrijati rernu na visoku temperaturu( ja sam pekla na 550F).
Peci nekoliko minuta i kad porumene okrenuti na drugu stranu i peci par minuta.
(ja sam ih pekla na kamenoj ploci za pizzu, koju sam ugrijala u rerni, a moze i na poledjini tepsije)
5
Peceni naan premazati sa puterom po zelji.</item>

    </string-array>  
        <string-array name="Americano"> 
       <item>PripremaTežina:Jednostavno
1
Germu zamutiti sa vodom i secerom i ostaviti da nadodje
2
Brasno prosijati, dodati nadoslu germu, jaje , mljieko i so.
Dodavati postepeno toplu vodu dok se ne dobije glatko tijesto ljepljivo za prste.
Ostaviti da nadodje, zatim podijeliti na manje loptice ( meni je izaslo osam).
3
Oblikovati ih i ostaviti da nadodju jos 15-tak minuta.
Razvuci lagano tijesto, oklagijom ili rukama, debljine oko 1 cm.
4
U medjuvremenu zagrijati rernu na visoku temperaturu( ja sam pekla na 550F).
Peci nekoliko minuta i kad porumene okrenuti na drugu stranu i peci par minuta.
(ja sam ih pekla na kamenoj ploci za pizzu, koju sam ugrijala u rerni, a moze i na poledjini tepsije)
5
Peceni naan premazati sa puterom po zelji.</item>

    </string-array>  
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) is what you need.

Why do you use a "string-array" if you have only one item in it ?
Use "string" instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="Naan"> 
       PripremaTežina:Jednostavno
1
Germu zamutiti sa vodom i secerom i ostaviti da nadodje
2
Brasno prosijati, dodati nadoslu germu, jaje , mljieko i so.
Dodavati postepeno toplu vodu dok se ne dobije glatko tijesto ljepljivo za prste.
Ostaviti da nadodje, zatim podijeliti na manje loptice ( meni je izaslo osam).
3
Oblikovati ih i ostaviti da nadodju jos 15-tak minuta.
Razvuci lagano tijesto, oklagijom ili rukama, debljine oko 1 cm.
4
U medjuvremenu zagrijati rernu na visoku temperaturu( ja sam pekla na 550F).
Peci nekoliko minuta i kad porumene okrenuti na drugu stranu i peci par minuta.
(ja sam ih pekla na kamenoj ploci za pizzu, koju sam ugrijala u rerni, a moze i na poledjini tepsije)
5
Peceni naan premazati sa puterom po zelji.

    </string>  
        <string name="Americano"> 
       PripremaTežina:Jednostavno
1
Germu zamutiti sa vodom i secerom i ostaviti da nadodje
2
Brasno prosijati, dodati nadoslu germu, jaje , mljieko i so.
Dodavati postepeno toplu vodu dok se ne dobije glatko tijesto ljepljivo za prste.
Ostaviti da nadodje, zatim podijeliti na manje loptice ( meni je izaslo osam).
3
Oblikovati ih i ostaviti da nadodju jos 15-tak minuta.
Razvuci lagano tijesto, oklagijom ili rukama, debljine oko 1 cm.
4
U medjuvremenu zagrijati rernu na visoku temperaturu( ja sam pekla na 550F).
Peci nekoliko minuta i kad porumene okrenuti na drugu stranu i peci par minuta.
(ja sam ih pekla na kamenoj ploci za pizzu, koju sam ugrijala u rerni, a moze i na poledjini tepsije)
5
Peceni naan premazati sa puterom po zelji.

    </string>  
</resources>
```

Then, simply do :

```
String sastojci = "";
if(product.equals("Naan"))
    sastojci = getString(R.string.naan);
...
```

Comment: hmm,you are suggesting i write a lot of if-s? will try that out, ty :)

Comment: all right,that with the ifs worked out just fine! thank you very much florian :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope your xml file is in a server and you are trying to display that xml file in your android app. I have a few suggestions

- Use `ListView`
- Use XML Parser to parse the xml from the server
- Populate the result in a `ListView`
- Create another `Activity` to show the child values of xml parent

Have a look at this:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: my xml file is a xml file stored in the resource folder...so its not a server :) i am using listview and was hoping to avoid parsing :) ty

Comment: Please see the link, if its not from server you can do it easily just skip the XML fetch from server and use your local XML